# Is it possible to create users that can only use one directory?

Tags: permissions, folder, directory

Now I've bought an Ubuntu Cloud server. I installed Webmin this morning, and now I have a question.

Is it possible to create users that can only use one directory, SVN, FTP, PHP, Python, MySQL, Apache? So for example, user Kevin only may use /var/www/kevin/? And he may view everything in /var/www/ but not execute/write and all other stuff is forbidden to view/execute/write.

Answer (score 5):

In your situation, you've the owner of the folder and its directories, say `apache`. `Kevin` is the user which is allowed to read the contents, but not write or execute it. All others are denied read, write and execute permissions.

This fits perfectly in the Linux filesystem permissions system.

```
permission  bits
  Read       4
  Write      2
 eXecute     1
```

Each file or directory can be given permissions based on the owner, group or everyone else.

- The owner (`apache`) can do anything, so let's give it read and write permissions (4 + 2 = `6`)
- To prepare for the future, in case you need to give someone other Kevin read permissions to the file, create a new group, say `apache-users`. Then, add Kevin to this group and set the group permission bits to `4` (**R**ead)
- Next, deny anyone who do not own the file or is not a member of the `apache-users` group all permissions, `0`.

To add the group `apache-users` and add Kevin as a member, go to *System* -> *Users and Groups*. Open the tab *Local Groups* and press *Create a new group*. Enter the group name (`apache-users`) at *Group name*. Select Kevin at *Members* and press *->*. Confirm these changes by pressing *Create*.

For a file, you would run the next commands to change the owner, group and permissions:

```
sudo chown apache filename
sudo chgrp apache-users filename
sudo chmod 640 filename
```

#### Directories

The permissions for directories are almost the same, except for the execute bit (`1`). The execute bit configures whether an user is allowed to descend in the directory, i.e. access other files and directories inside a directory. The read bit controls whether you can list the contents of a directory (`ls`).

So if a folder `/dir` is owned by root:root (group root), and the permissions of `/dir/file` is set to 777, you cannot access (read, write or execute) `/dir/file` if the permissions of `/dir` is set to 666 or 770 (note the missing eXecute permission).

The permissions for a folder would become 750: read, write and execute (`7`) for the owner (`apache`), read and execute (`5`) for the group (`apache-users`) and no permissions (`0`) for anyone else.

For your setup, the permissions become (`*` = depends):

```
location             owner     group        permissions
/                    root      root         755
/var/                root      root         755
/var/www/            root      root         755
/var/www/kevin/      kevin     *            700 or 750
/var/www/apache/     apache    apache-users 750
/var/www/other/      *         *            700 or 750
/var/www/anyoneread/ *         *            755
```

`/var/www/other/` is the directory of some other user which do not allow you (kevin) to dive in the directory.